# Unassign method in Bonita 6.5.4 exists?

Tags: javascript, groovy, bonita

with two task named "View" and "Register" its needed to implement a Unassign Button from Management user in taskUser Level in a Service Task connector these two tasks using unassign(method needed) and release(releaseUserTask) for another user have a chance to view and register.

in others words, need a rollback for the instanceprocess from the UserTask cancel request("View" and "Request") to before he presses the "Do It" buttom of the "View Task". Cancelling all interation and Data Input of TaskUser to that point.

How i can do this? Remembering that releaseUserTask is only used when have Unclaim Task or Unassign.

Cheers
Peter Grant.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only method to unassign a human task is releaseUserTask. Did you try to use it to implement your use case?

Cheers